# How to do a MySQL Insert if unique, but the columns are too long for unique index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have found a great answer for when inserting a new record, ignore if the data already exists.

1) Create a UNIQUE INDEX on the columns.

2) INSERT IGNORE INTO ...

But my problem is that one of the columns is a VARCHAR(2000)**, and MySQL has a 1000-character limit to indexes.

The columns are: id (int), type (varchar 35), data (varchar 2000)

So is there a way to make sure I'm not adding the same data twice with a single query? Or do I need to do a select first to check for existence and if false, perform the insert?

Thanks.

** This is not design, I'm just moving data around so no chance of making this column smaller.

Comment: Seems to me `id` should be enough to save you from duplicates. Might be wrong.

Comment: I guess I should add that id is not a unique value. ID is the foreign key of another table. Type would be all the parameters that go to that ID. So you'd have 100/account_id/1234, 100/name/John Doe, 100/email/email@email.com, etc...

Comment: So `id` and `type` together are the primary key right? No need for the `data` to be unique then.

Comment: Incorrect. The table I'm pulling from may have multiple 100/account_id/1234 records and i just want one. And no, I can't use distinct as where this is stored and where my tables are on different servers and cannot be linked. No chance at getting SQL Dumps, either. This is run query on remote server, copy and paste results into program that can read the output and insert everything into a local table. Can't use DISTINCT on the remote server query either because the data comes in a different format: 100/1234/John Doe/email@email.com. I parse out each possible response for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Given the table design you mentioned:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    type varchar(35),
    data varchar(2000),
    primary key (id)
);
```

Your best chance would be the following:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable_new LIKE mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new ADD COLUMN data_hash CHAR(40);
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new ADD UNIQUE INDEX (data_hash);

INSERT INTO mydb.mytable_new (id,type,data,data_hash)
  SELECT id,type,data,UPPER(SHA(data)) FROM mydb.mytable;

ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable RENAME mydb.mytable_old;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new RENAME mydb.mytable;
DROP TABLE mydb.mytable_old;
```

Once you add this new column and index, table should now look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    type varchar(35),
    data varchar(2000),
    data_hash char(40),
    primary key (id),
    unique key data_hash (data_hash)
);
```

Simply perform your operations as follows:

## INSERTs

```
INSERT INTO mydb.mytable (type,data,data_hash)
VALUES ('somtype','newdata',UPPER(SHA('newdata')));
```

INSERTs should fail on data_hash is you attempt a duplicate key insertion

## SELECTs

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable
WHERE data_hash = UPPER(SHA('data_I_am_searching_for'));
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Hashes have collisions so unless you don’t care about that, this is not a foolproof solution